# Implement custom .fit() method for model in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using a number of pipelines to compare in cross validation. As a benchmark model I want to include a simple model which uses always the same fixed coefficient, and hence, doesn't depend on the training data. In order to get the model I want I have decided to inherit all of the behaviour of sklearns linear model and implement my own .fit() method, which in fact doesn't look at the train data, but always uses a stored model.

When using my custom implementation as a model it works fine, however, as part of a pipeline I get a *NotFittedError*.

Creating my simple benchmark model and storing it:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
y = [10,20,30]

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X,y)
pickle.dump(model, open('benchmark_model.txt', 'wb'))
print (model.coef_)
```

> [10.]

Defining my own benchmark_model() which implements custom fit method. The fit method opens the stored model

```
class benchmark_model(LinearRegression):
      def fit(self, X, y = None):
            self = pickle.load(open('benchmark_model.txt', 'rb')) 
            return self
```

Testing the custom fit implementation as model on different data seems to go well.

```
X=np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
y=[5,10,15]

model = benchmark_model()
model = model.fit(X,y)

print (model.coef_)
print (model.predict(X))
```

> [10.]
>   [10. 20. 30.]

Now, I am first using a normal LinearRegression as part of a pipeline, which seems to go as expected:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('model',LinearRegression())])
pipe.fit(X,y).predict(X)
```

> array([ 5., 10., 15.])

However, when I use my custom benchmark model as part of the pipeline it doesn't work anymore.

```
pipe = Pipeline([('model',benchmark_model())])
pipe.fit(X,y).predict(X)
```

> NotFittedError: This benchmark_model instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the pipeline gets confused when `benchmark_model.fit()` returns an instance of class `LinearRegression` instead of `benchmark_model`. It seems to work, if instead we just copy the learned parameters from the fixed model:

```py
class benchmark_model(LinearRegression):
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        fixed_model = pickle.load(open('benchmark_model.txt', 'rb')) 
        self.coef_ = fixed_model.coef_
        self.intercept_ = fixed_model.intercept_
        return self
```

Now `fit` actually returns an instance of `benchmark_model`.